# Using different parameters for POST request in second method

Tags: c#, json, http-post, static-methods, restsharp

In the code below, `GetResults()` is using value of `response.Content` from `GetAddress()`:

```
"{\"result\":\"someaddress\",\"error\":null,\"id\":\"rpctest\"}\n"
```

This is wrong as it should be using new request parameters defined in the method. So I get this error when I run the application:

```
System.Text.Json.JsonException: 'The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Myapp.mainResult]. Path: $.result | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 54.'
```

I tried adding this in `GetResults()` before adding new parameters but it does not work and gives null JSON error:

```
restParams.request.Parameters.Clear();
```

```cs
    namespace Myapp
    {
        public class mainResult
        {
            public string address { get; set; }
            public string email { get; set; }
            public bool remote { get; set; }
        }
    
        public class Params
        {
            public RestClient? client { get; set; }
            public RestRequest? request { get; set; }
        }
    
        public class Addresses
        {
            public string? address { get; set; }
        }
    
        public class addResponse
        {
            public string result { get; set; }
            public object error { get; set; }
            public string id { get; set; }
        }
    
        public class mainResponse
        {
            public List<mainResult> result { get; set; }
            public object error { get; set; }
            public string id { get; set; }
        }
    
        public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            private static Params restParams = new Params();
            private static Addresses home_addresses = new Addresses();
            private static addResponse addResponse = new addResponse();
            private static mainResponse mainResponse = new mainResponse();
    
            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();            
    
                if (ConnectServer())
                {
                    new_address.Content = GetAddress();
                    SaveAddress();
                }
            }
    
            public static bool ConnectServer()
            {
                try
                {
                    restParams.client = new RestClient("http://localhost:8080");
                    restParams.client.Timeout = -1;
                    restParams.request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
                    restParams.request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic ZDhjZGUyNDIzNDhhNmQwNTIwZGI1ZjcyNjk");
                    restParams.request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.Write(ex.ToString());
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
    
            public static string GetAddress()
            {
                const string? body = @"{""jsonrpc"": ""1.0"", ""id"": ""rpctest"", ""method"": ""getaddress"", ""params"": [""test""]}";
                restParams.request.AddParameter("application/json", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
                IRestResponse response = restParams.client.Execute(restParams.request);
    
                addResponse newaddress = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<addResponse>(response.Content);
    
                home_addresses.address = newaddress.result;            
    
                return home_addresses.address;
            }
    
            public static async void SaveAddress()
            {
                string address = home_addresses.address;
    
                string json_path = @"E:\address_test.json";
    
                if (!File.Exists(json_path))
                {
                    await using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(json_path))
                    {
                        writer.WriteLine(address);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    await using (StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(json_path))
                    {
                        writer.WriteLine(address);
                    }
                }
            }
    
            public static List<mainResult> GetResults()
            {
                
                const string? body = @"{""jsonrpc"": ""1.0"", ""id"": ""rpctest"", ""method"": ""getresults"", ""params"": []}";
                restParams.request.AddParameter("application/json", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
    
                IRestResponse response = restParams.client.Execute(restParams.request);
    
                mainResponse main_response = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<mainResponse>(response.Content);
    
                mainResponse.result = main_response.result;
    
                return mainResponse.result;
            }
    
            private void getresults_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                mylist.AppendText(GetResults().ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

What is wrong with the code and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

when i convert your json to c# class below class is correct:

```
public class Root
    {
        public string result { get; set; }
        public object error { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
    }
```

below link convert your json to c# class:
[https://json2csharp.com/]

Comment: Problem is not wrong JSON or its C# code. It's the use of REST parameters in `GetResults()` method. It's using value from other method: `GetAddress()`

Answer (score 0):

when you use @  you do not need add
""
is is correct body:

const string? body =@"{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id": "rpctest", "method": "getresults", "params": []}";